# How can aluminium cables be lengthened for automotive environment?

Tags: cables, automotive

My company's business is stretching and armouring cars. In the former process we must also lengthen all the wires. We've just come across aluminium cables, which pose a problem — until now we used to cut and solder the cables together with the extension.

The sections we have to deal with are (in mm²):

- 0.5
- 0.75
- 1
- 1.5
- 2.5

I'd like to know what [industrial] options are available to stretch aluminium cables. There is one possibility that is out of question: replacing entire cables with longer ones. We don't have all the connectors since not every single of them is available, some are proprietary and brand-specific. So we're left with actually "stretch" the cables.

So what are the available options?

Comment: Stretching the cables will reduce the cross-section leaving them undersized. Try cutting them and fixing crimp terminals to the ends.

Comment: I would think by saying "stretching" he means "lengthening".

Comment: Aluminum wiring is extremely problematic. I am surprised it is used in a high vibration environment such as an automobile. I think the only reliable way to lengthen it will be with some type of crimp connection specifically designed for aluminum wire.

Comment: You can look into Burndy aluminum compression fittings. Seems like they MIGHT work. E.g., http://www.burndy.com/docs/default-source/cutsheets/aluminum-splices-cutsheet.pdf?sfvrsn=0

Comment: Are they definitely aluminium and not simply tinned copper?

Comment: @Tyler Exact, I mean "lengthening". I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewMorton They indeed are made of aluminium. Tin solder doesn't stick. After inspection it appears that more than half of the cables are now made of aluminium on the Toyota Land Cruiser 200 we are working on. Mercedes also have started to use thick, power alu. cables.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks, seems to be a good possibility. I'll check with my supplier if they can provide us with some of these.

Comment: Well, if Toyota and Mercedes are doing it, they have probably done enough research to determine how to overcome the inherent problems with Aluminum. Most interesting!

Comment: Also, look to AMP Copalum.  This sytem is said to be Expensive.  They rent the tools and require factory training.  It has a good reputation however.

Comment: @RobertEndl I looked up for Copalum splices and the price is huge! Look at https://www.ttiinc.com/content/ttiinc/en.html then type `Copalum Splices TE Connectivity` (Shame their web site doesn't allow deep-search links! Web designers don't learn. Sighs.) Some parts are more than $100 each! We'd rather use sleeves or something that is quick enough — we have between 50 and 100 cables to lengthen for each vehicle, depending on the brand. Any hint?

Comment: Soldering cables in a stretched car is bad practice. The point between litz wire copper and the solder joint is a predetermined breaking point. There are a lot of crimp connectors for this purpose. Are there any solder joints of cables in the original car?

Comment: @Uwe No there aren't. What would you recommend for 100-200 cables (per car) to extend?

Comment: I would recommend crimp connectors for automotive use. Soldering those cables is a problem in an automotive environment with a lot of vibration. Such solder connections may break eventually, in some month or some years. But when they break your customer and your company will get problems. You will need different connectors for the different cable sections.

Comment: What about heat shrink butt connectors like this one here:

https://www.johnstonesupply.com/storefront/supplies/electrical-installation-maintenance-supplies/terminals-connectors/heat-shrink-connectors/c1027909-c1027123-c1026872-c1028385-p1.html?sorter=popularity-desc

Comment: Nasha...That's what I found.  Someone suggested looking to the auto harness makers, and they may be right.  I have seen products for Al wiring over the years, but lack of a market seems to have killed them off.  AMP for example had a crip system that no longer seems to be around.  The power distribution people use aluminum but big cables, not small wires.  They often use a nickel-filled grease to passivate the wire surface, and this "might" be helpfull for you.

Comment: AMP has a system of splices and lugs called Copalum.  But, they are for large wires/cables.  !4 AWG is the smallest they mention.  Other companies (like Burndy) have similar.

Comment: @RobertEndl Thanks, I'll investigate that direction.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** solder aluminium, or at least certain grades. I can solder to cooking grade aluminium foil for instance.

The trick is to buy a specialist multicore solder, with a particularly nasty aggressive flux in it. I find it easiest to 'tin' all the surfaces, then use conventional solder to complete the joint. It needs some practice to get the solder to take, especially getting the temperature right. I don't know whether it is still available, I bought mine 3 decades ago, and still have some left!

One alternative is screw clamps, another is crimp. I'm not sure either would be too robust against possible corrosion of the mating surfaces, unless scrupulously encapsulated after joining. Both would be larger profile than soldering.

Comment: And under *no* circumstances should you attempt to connect aluminum to copper using either method unless you are using connectors specifically designed for such.

Comment: Even those "approved" for aluminum can be less than reliable.  Anything you use should be researched first.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution:[image]  Tulsonic

Comment: Does your distinctly short and non-descriptive answer refer to the bonding method of [this company](http://www.telsonic.com/en/metal-welding/)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with aluminum wire is that the conductor "cold-flows"  when crimped with standard crimp splices.

The most reliable splice that I use is a standard electrical Marrette splice cap. This has a conical spring inside that tightly grips the conductors. These are reliable for decades.

Although I regularly solder aluminum using specialty solder and Flux, it just doesn't seem to be as reliable as a Marrette splice cap.

The downside of Marrette splice caps is that they are physically large.

Comment: Twist-on splice connectors are probably not rated for use in high-vibration environments.

Comment: Marette splice caps definitely don't apply here. They've been used in the past and proven totally unreliable. Most of all they don't circumvent the problem of humidity on the exposed wires.